# Can Verity search a SQL database on a different server?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, verity

We have Verity running successfully on our small library website.

We have our Library catalog on a different server and it runs off an SQL database.

We would like to see if we can get Verity to search the catalog while also searching our site.

I have had trouble finding any documentation that could steer us in the right direction. Does anyone know if this is even possible and how we could go about doing it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. CFINDEX supports a query attribute. You first need to create a new collection. Then, you'll have to query the SQL server you're trying to search against, and give the name of that query variable to CFINDEX along with the name of the new collection. Once you do this, you can then use CFSEARCH to search against data in your new collection. More information about CFINDEX can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_i_06.html#1100286).